# Grunt not working for auto reference css and js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I'm currently face an issue for grunt server, when I run grunt, it still only load and generate path for the default scss, and js (my project was generated by yeoman webapp generator)

here is my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "securechat",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "alertify": "~0.3.10",
    "keymaster": "~1.6.2"
  }
}
```

Should I put js info under dependencies or devDependencies? why my grunt not working for auto reference css and js

My scss file all under app/sytles folder 
An empty main.js file so far under app/scripts

Gruntfile.js was generated from yeoman webapp generator, with sass and modernizr selected.

Answer (score 0):

After I change the bower.json structure to

```
{
  "name": "securechat",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.9.0",
     "alertify": "~0.3.10",
    "keymaster": "~1.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

It works, but only cannot auto reference the css file under bower_components, if that package got css file as well.